`Vo we l spa ci ng`
Today you are having a silly problem.
To da  y   yo    u     a      re       ha        vi         ng          a           si            lly             pro              ble               m.

Challenge
Given an English text, apply "vo wel  spa   ci    ng" (see below).
Input
One line of string with these constraints:

Consist of letters of both cases, space, comma and period.
At least 1 letter and at most (at your choice) 15, 16, 31, 32 or 50 letters.
Match /^([A-Za-z]+[.,]? )*[A-Za-z]+[.,]?$/ in POSIX ERE; in English, it's a list of space-separated words with just letters but no punctuation; some words may contain a punctuation of either a full stop or a comma but not both. No leading spaces, no trailing spaces, separated with exactly one space.

Output
Result of "vo wel  spa   ci    ng". Your output may have trailing spaces but no leading spaces.
"Vo we  l   spa    ci     ng" specification
The "Vo we  l   spa    ci     ng" is an algorithm which takes a string of input to return a string of output. The procedure is:

For each vowel that is NOT the last letter of its word, append a space.
For each space (let it N-th space. 1-indexed), replace it with N spaces.
The implementation of this algorithm may append some spaces to the end of the string.
Return the final string.

In the procedure above, I define the following terms:

A vowel is a letter that is one of the following ten letter: AEIOUaeiou.
A word is a consequence concatenation of one or more letters but nothing else: e.g. "word", "WORD", "wOrD", "w", "o", "r", or "d" but not "word,",  "word.", or "w o r d"
The last letter of the word is: (a) if it has only a letter, then the letter is the last letter of the word. (b) Otherwise (i.e. it has two or more letters), the last letter of the word without first letter is the last letter of the word. E.g. "word" => "d", "A" => "A".
A space is a character which delimits each word; the character is not a punctuation or a letter. In ASCII, the character with code point of 0x20.

Test cases
The format is:
Input
=> Output

Here are test cases. Very wide:
Input
=> I npu  t

Output
=> O u  tpu   t

Test cases
=> Te st  ca   se    s

Hello, world.
=> He llo,  wo   rld.

Vowel Spacing
=> Vo we  l   Spa    ci     ng

Today you are having a silly problem.
=> To da  y   yo    u     a      re       ha        vi         ng          a           si            lly             pro              ble               m.

Code Golf and Code Challenge StackExchange
=> Co de  Go   lf    a     nd      Co       de        Cha         lle          nge           Sta            ckE             xcha              nge

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
=> A A  A   A    A     A      A       A        A         A          A           A            A             A              A               A                A                 A                  A                   A                    A

BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
=> BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

QwErTyUiOp AsDfGhJkL zXcVbNm
=> QwE rTyU  i   O    p     A      sDfGhJkL       zXcVbNm

qWeRtYuIoP aSdFgHjKl ZxCvBnM
=> qWe RtYu  I   o    P     a      SdFgHjKl       ZxCvBnM

Given an English text,
=> Gi ve  n   a    n     E      ngli       sh        te         xt,

apply vo we l spa ci ng.
=> a pply  vo   we    l     spa      ci       ng.

rhythm
=> rhythm

FORTRAN LISP COBOL ALGOL
=> FO RTRA  N   LI    SP     CO      BO       L        A         LGO          L

This is code golf. Shortest code wins.
=> Thi s  i   s    co     de      go       lf.        Sho         rte          st           co            de             wi              ns.

I
=> I

am here to, kick out, leading spaces.
=> a m  he   re    to,     ki      ck       o        u         t,          le           a            di             ng              spa               ce                s.

Rules

code-golf
See also https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defaults

Non-competing implementation example in shell script
In ksh. Coding-style
#!/bin/sh

# Usage: f.sh
# Reads one line from standard input.
# Outputs the result to standard output.

# == Function ==
# Get random value N; suitable for awk srand()
randseed() {
  (ps -Ao pid,etime,pcpu,vsz; date) |
  od -An -td4 |
  sed 's/[^-0-9]\{1,8\}/&\n/g' |
  grep . |
  tail -n42 |
  awk -v a=-2147483648 '
  { a += $0; }; END { print a; }
  '
}
seed="$( randseed )"

# == Main ==
# Separate each word and optionally a trailing punctuation by line.
# Replace "@" to indicate original space.
awk '{
  for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
    if ( i >= 2 ) print "@";
    print $i;
  }
}' |
#
# 1. word and optionally a punctuation 
# OR
# 1. "@" to indicate space
#
# Insert a newline before the punctuation.
sed 's/[.,]/\n&/g' |
#
# 1. word OR 1. punctuation OR 1. "@"
#
# Prepare for step 1 for each word:
# append a space to each vowel
sed 's/[AEIOUaeiou]/& /g' |
#
# 1-N. space-separated word, separated after vowel
# OR 1. punctuation OR 1. "@"
#
# Now do step 1: append a space-sign "@" to non-last chunk of words.
awk '
/[@.,]/ { print; next; }

# word
{
  for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
    if ( i >= 2 ) print "@";
    print $i;
  }
}' |
#
# 1. "@" OR 1. word or punctuation
#
# Prepare for step 2: enumerate each "@"
awk -v N=1 '
/@/ { print N++, $0; next; }
1' |
#
# 1. Space number 2. "@"
# OR 1. else
#
# Now do step 2: replace N-th space with N spaces.
awk '
NF == 2 {
  for ( ; $1--; ) print "@";
  next;
}
1' |
#
# 1. value
#
# Do step 3: append random number of spaces to the sentence.
awk 'BEGIN {
  srand('"$seed"');
  maxspaces = 3;
}
1;
END {
  x = rand()*(maxspaces+1);
  x = int(x);
  while ( x-- ) print "@";
}' |
#
# 1. value
#
# Finally do step 4: result of sentence.
awk -v reslt= '
/@/ { reslt = reslt " "; next; }
1   { reslt = reslt $0;        }
END { print reslt; }
'

# == Finish ==
exit 0

Try it online!
See also

vo we  l   spa    ci     ng on Anarchy Golf. Origin of this challenge. Not https.

Sandbox

Vyxal, 16 bytes
⇧a?Aǔ*ÞṗṠ⌈fꜝ₅ɽ꘍∑

Try it Online!
I don't like this but it's probably optimal. +4 bytes due to the weird punctuation requirement that isn't at all clearly specified.
      Þṗ         # Partition before indices where
    ǔ            # The character before
  ?A             # is a vowel
     *           # And 
⇧a               # The character after is a letter
        Ṡ        # Concatenate each
         ⌈f      # Split each on spaces and flatten
           ꜝ     # Remove empty strings after words ending with vowels. (this also condenses spaces but we don't have to handle that)
              ꘍  # Pad each with spaces by
            ₅ɽ   # range from 1 to its length exclusive
                ∑ # Concatenate the result


JavaScript (Node.js), 49 bytes
x=>x.replace(/ |(?<=[aeiou])\B/gi,_=>c+=' ',c='')

Try it online!
-4 bytes Neil

(?=\w) can be \B to save 4 bytes.

Sed, 45 bytes
s/[aouei]\B/&_/gi
y/ /_/
:a
s/_/ &/g
s/_//
ta

We use _ as a placeholder for the spaces we add (line 1) and any pre-existing spaces (line 2), then we loop (line 3), adding a space to all the placeholders (line 4) and removing the first one (line 5), repeating the loop until no more placeholders remain (line 6).
We can see the progression if we add some debug printing in the loop:
l
s/[aouei]\B/&_/gi
y/ /_/
:a
l
s/_/ &/g
s/_//
ta

fo am to, ex.$
fo_a_m_to,_e_x.$
fo a _m _to, _e _x.$
fo a  m  _to,  _e  _x.$
fo a  m   to,   _e   _x.$
fo a  m   to,    e    _x.$
fo a  m   to,    e     x.$

Try it online.

Jelly, 19 bytes
e€ØWḊae€Øc$kKfƤẹ¦¥⁶

Try it online!
A bit of a mess with the word logic, but I'm pretty proud of how I golfed the actual spacing 3 bytes down from ḲµJ⁶xⱮż@!
      e€               For each character, is it
        Øc             a vowel,
     a    $            and is
    Ḋ                  the character after it
e€ØW                   a word character?
    Ḋa                 (The end of the string can be a false positive but yeah.)
           k           Split the string after those characters,
                 ¥     then
            K          join on spaces
                ¦      and replace characters at
               ẹ  ⁶    indices of spaces
             fƤ   ⁶    with the string up to that point filtered to spaces.


05AB1E, 27 26 bytes
ü2ε¬lžMÃ«ágÍ}0šÅ¡Jðý#íāúíJ

Try it online or verify all test cases.
Or alternatively:
Ćü2ε¬DŠlžMÃ«ágÍið«]J#íāúíJ

Try it online or verify all test cases.
It feels way too long, but I'm not seeing it.. :/
Explanation:
ü2               # Get all overlapping pairs of the (implicit) input
  ε              # Map over each pair:
   ¬             #  Push the first character of the pair (without popping)
    l            #  Convert it to lowercase
     žMÃ         #  Only keep the vowels "aeiou"
        «        #  Append it to the pair
         á       #  Only keep the letters of this now pair or triplet
          g      #  Pop and push its length
           Í     #  Decrease it by 2
  }0š            # After the map: prepend a leading 0
     Å¡          # Split the (implicit) input before every truthy (==1) position
                 # (side effect: parts become lists of characters)
       J         # Join each inner list of characters back to a string
        ðý       # Then join this list of parts with a space delimiter
          #      # Split it by spaces
í                # Reverse each part
 ā               # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
  ú              # Pad each reversed string with that amount of leading spaces
   í             # Reverse the strings back, since we wanted trailing spaces
    J            # Join everything together
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)

Ć                # Enclose; append its own first character to the (implicit) input
 ü2              # Pop and get all overlapping pairs
   ε             # Map over each pair:
    ¬            #  Push the first character of the pair (without popping)
     D           #  Duplicate it
      Š          #  Triple-swap [pair,head,head] to [head,pair,head] 
     lžMÃ«ágÍ    #  Similar as above
             i   #  If this is truthy (==1):
              ð« #   Append a space to the head
   ]             # Close both the if-statement and map
    J            # Join everything together
     #íāúíJ      # Same as above
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)


Charcoal, 33 bytes
ＦＳ«Ｆ№⁺ ω↧ι⭆⊞Ｏυ¹ Ｆ›ι ι≔×β№aeiou↧ιω

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
ＦＳ«

Loop through the input string.
Ｆ№⁺ ω↧ι

If the current character is a space, or it is a letter and the previous character was a vowel, then...
⭆⊞Ｏυ¹ 

...output one more space than last time.
Ｆ›ι ι

Output the current character if it is not a space.
≔×β№aeiou↧ιω

Remember whether the current character is a vowel for the next pass.
Alternative approach, also 33 bytes:
⭆⪪⭆θ⎇∧κ∧№β↧ι№aeiou↧§θ⊖κ⁺ ιι ⁺× κι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
   θ                                Input string
  ⭆                                 Map over characters and join
      κ                             Current index
     ∧                              Logical And
        №                           Count of
           ι                        Current character
          ↧                         Lowercased
         β                          In predefined variable lowercase alphabet
       ∧                            Logical And
            №                       Count of
                    θ               Input string
                   §                Indexed by
                      κ             Current index
                     ⊖              Decremented
                  ↧                 Lowercased
             aeiou                  In literal string `aeiou`
    ⎇                               If true then
                                    Literal space
                       ⁺            Concatenated with
                         ι          Current character
                          ι         Else current character
 ⪪                                  Split on spaces
⭆                                   Map over each part and join
                                    Literal space
                             ×      Repeated by
                               κ    Current index
                            ⁺       Plus
                                ι   Current part
                                    Implicitly print


Retina 0.8.2, 37 bytes
i`[aeiou]\B
$& 
 (?<=(( )|.)+)
$#2$* 

Try it online! Link includes test cases. Explanation:
i`[aeiou]\B
$& 

Insert spaces after every non-trailing vowel in either upper or lower case.
 (?<=(( )|.)+)
$#2$* 

Replace each space with the spaces so far, obtained by counting them in a lookbehind and then repeating a space by the count.
24 bytes in Retina 1:
i` |([aeiou])\B
$1$>:&* 

Try it online! Link includes test cases. Explanation: $>:& gives the match index, which is then used to repeat spaces, so all that remains is to replace all of the spaces and append to all of the non-trailing vowels.

Vyxal s, 136 bitsv2, 17 bytes
øWƛṫ$ƛA꘍;p∑;ṅƛð=[&›¥I

Try it Online!
Bitstring:
0001011010100000000000101000111001001011011000111111100111100100001000101110110101111001100100010101101111110101110101000000101011011000

A very silly approach
Explained
øWƛṫ$ƛA꘍;p∑;ṅƛð=[&›¥I­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁡​‎‏​⁢⁠⁢‌­
øW                     # ‎⁡Split on words (i.e. spaces, but also punctuation, etc)
  ƛ     ;              # ‎⁢To each word:
   ṫ$                  # ‎⁣  Push word[-1], word[:-1]
     ƛ  ;              # ‎⁤  To each character in word[:-1]
      A꘍               # ‎⁢⁡    Append a space if the character is a vowel
         p             # ‎⁢⁢  Add the last letter back to the end
          ∑            # ‎⁢⁣  Join into a single string
            ṅ          # ‎⁢⁤Join the list of modified words back into a sentence
             ƛ         # ‎⁣⁡To each character:
              ð=       # ‎⁣⁢  If it's a space:
                 &›    # ‎⁣⁣    Increment the register (starts at 0)
                   ¥I  # ‎⁣⁤    and then push that many spaces
‎⁤⁡The s flag joins the result into a single string


Created with the help of Luminespire.

Pip, 21 bytes
aR-XV.`\B`_.sRssX{Ui}

Attempt This Online!
Explanation
aR-XV.`\B`_.sRssX{Ui}
a                     ; Command-line input
 R                    ; Replace:
   XV                 ;  Regex matching a vowel
  -                   ;  Case-insensitive
     .                ;  Concatenate
      `\B`            ;  Regex matching non-word-boundary (next character is a letter)
                      ; with:
          _           ;  The matched character
           .s         ;  Concatenated with a space
             R        ; Then, replace:
              s       ;  Space
                      ; with:
                 {Ui} ;  Increment i (initially 0)
               sX     ;  That many spaces


Ruby, 43 bytes
->x{x.gsub(/ |(?<=[aeiou])\B/i){' '*$.+=1}}

Attempt this online!
Simply a direct port of l4m2's JavaScript solution. Uses the global $. which counts which line of input we are 'up to' so always starts at 0. Had to reset it to 0 manually in the header only because I wanted to repeat the function on all the test cases. I formatted the ATO link so that correct solutions are shown above the code's output for comparison.

Interestingly, I thought that I should be able to replace (?<=[aeiou]) with [aeiou]\K in Ruby, but it no longer matches all the post-vowel positions for some reason...

AWK, 118 bytes
BEGIN{FS=X}{for(;++i<=NF;){d=d$i
$i~/ /&&(d=d y)&&y=y" "
$i~/[AEIOUaeiou]/&&$(i+1)!~/[ \.,]/&&(y=y" ")&&d=d y}print d}

Try it online!
BEGIN{FS=X}                  # split input by character
{for(;++i<=NF;){d=d$i        # pop next letter onto string d
$i~/ /&&(d=d y)&&y=y" "      # special case for space
$i~/[AEIOUaeiou]/&&$(i+1)!~/[ \.,]/&&(y=y" ")&&d=d y}
print d}                     # ^vowel/punctuationmatching


Welcome to the CGCC! Nice first answer!

Python, 123 bytes
f=lambda s,j=0:"".join(x+" "*((j:=j+d)-(x<"!"))if x in"aeiouAEIOU "and(d:=(y in" ,.")<1)else x for x,y in zip(s,s[1:]+" "))

Attempt This Online!
Looking at the other solutions I'm pretty sure using regex would be shorter but this is the best I can do

Japt -Sx, 18 16 bytes
r"%v%B"Èú2Ã¸Ë+Eç

Try it
r"%v%B"Èú2Ã¸Ë+Eç     :Implicit input of string
r                    :Replace
 "%v%B"              :  RegEx /[aeiou]\B/gi
       È             :  Pass each match through the following function
        ú2           :    Right pad with spaces to length 2
          Ã          :End replace
           ¸         :Split on spaces
            Ë        :Map each element at 0-based index E
             +       :  Append
              Eç     :    Space repeated E times
                     :Implicit output joined with spaces and trimmed


ú is right pad, not left pad, correct?

Perl 5 -p, 33 bytes
s/[aeiou]\B\K/ /gi;s/ /$"x++$i/ge

Try it online!
